# Mongoose on update saves virtual populate to document

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

For some reason mongoose is not updating correctly. It is adding into my `Document` the virtuals.

```
const BlogSchema: Schema = new Schema<Blog>({
  clientId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
  }
  //...
})

ClientSchema.virtual('client', {
  ref: 'clients',
  localField: 'clientId',
  foreignField: '_id',
  justOne: true,
});

//...

return this.clientScreeningsModel
      .findById(id)
      .populate('client', 'email username')
      .lean(true);
```

This is working fine.

But on the client side I say I want to update or create a new `Document` and I send the entire `Object`

eg:

```
{
  _id: 'something',
  clientId: 'previousId',
  client: {
    email: 'foo@bar.com',
    username: 'JohnDoe'
  }
}
```

It will save the client object as well into my `Document`, Does mongoose not know that it is a virtual?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: As I cannot still find a solution I will go to their github :)